# UINavigationController-Alike for Desktop-Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently developing an application with an user interface much like Twitter for Mac (Pushing in/out of views like on iOS).

Has anyone implemented a UIViewController for desktop Cocoa? This would save me many hours of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one in standard AppKit at this time. You'll have to write your own.

This may help if you decide to go down that path: http://parsekit.com/umekit/

UMEKit is a little framework for Cocoa that implements some equivalents to UIKit classes and UI components.

Comment: For those still looking after all these years, this project seems very dead. Try the BFNavigationController answer below which still builds clean on Xcode 10

Comment: Do we have something with Navigation back also .. Like the UI In mac appstore?

Answer (score 4):

I spent ages looking for this and started to write my own, then found https://github.com/bfolder/BFNavigationController

For some reason Google doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 4):

Here how we did `NavigationController`, without navigation bar. Implementing navigation bar with transitions between navigation items similar to how transition between views made in example below.

```
import AppKit

public class NavigationController: NSViewController {

   public private (set) var viewControllers: [NSViewController] = []

   open override func loadView() {
      view = NSView()
      view.wantsLayer = true
   }

   public init(rootViewController: NSViewController) {
      super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
      pushViewController(rootViewController, animated: false)
   }

   public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError()
   }
}

extension NavigationController {

   public var topViewController: NSViewController? {
      return viewControllers.last
   }

   public func pushViewControllerAnimated(_ viewController: NSViewController) {
      pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
   }

   public func pushViewController(_ viewController: NSViewController, animated: Bool) {
      viewController.navigationController = self
      viewController.view.wantsLayer = true
      if animated, let oldVC = topViewController {
         embedChildViewController(viewController)
         let endFrame = oldVC.view.frame
         let startFrame = endFrame.offsetBy(dx: endFrame.width, dy: 0)
         viewController.view.frame = startFrame
         viewController.view.alphaValue = 0.85
         viewControllers.append(viewController)
         NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
            context.duration = 0.2
            context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
            context.timingFunction = .easeOut
            viewController.view.animator().frame = endFrame
            viewController.view.animator().alphaValue = 1
            oldVC.view.animator().alphaValue = 0.25
         }) {
            oldVC.view.alphaValue = 1
            oldVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
         }
      } else {
         embedChildViewController(viewController)
         viewControllers.append(viewController)
      }
   }

   @discardableResult
   public func popViewControllerAnimated() -> NSViewController? {
      return popViewController(animated: true)
   }

   @discardableResult
   public func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> NSViewController? {
      guard let oldVC = viewControllers.popLast() else {
         return nil
      }

      if animated, let newVC = topViewController {
         let endFrame = oldVC.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: oldVC.view.frame.width, dy: 0)
         view.addSubview(newVC.view, positioned: .below, relativeTo: oldVC.view)
         NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
            context.duration = 0.23
            context.allowsImplicitAnimation = true
            context.timingFunction = .easeIn
            oldVC.view.animator().frame = endFrame
            oldVC.view.animator().alphaValue = 0.85
         }) {
            self.unembedChildViewController(oldVC)
         }
      } else {
         unembedChildViewController(oldVC)
      }
      return oldVC
   }

}
```

Reusable extensions:

```
extension NSViewController {

   private struct OBJCAssociationKey {
      static var navigationController = "com.mc.navigationController"
   }

   public var navigationController: NavigationController? {
      get {
         return ObjCAssociation.value(from: self, forKey: &OBJCAssociationKey.navigationController)
      } set {
         ObjCAssociation.setAssign(value: newValue, to: self, forKey: &OBJCAssociationKey.navigationController)
      }
   }
}

extension NSViewController {

   public func embedChildViewController(_ vc: NSViewController, container: NSView? = nil) {
      addChildViewController(vc)
      vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
      vc.view.autoresizingMask = [.height, .width]
      (container ?? view).addSubview(vc.view)
   }

   public func unembedChildViewController(_ vc: NSViewController) {
      vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
      vc.removeFromParentViewController()
   }
}

struct ObjCAssociation {

   static func value<T>(from object: AnyObject, forKey key: UnsafeRawPointer) -> T? {
      return objc_getAssociatedObject(object, key) as? T
   }

   static func setAssign<T>(value: T?, to object: Any, forKey key: UnsafeRawPointer) {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(object, key, value, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN)
   }

   static func setRetainNonAtomic<T>(value: T?, to object: Any, forKey key: UnsafeRawPointer) {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(object, key, value, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
   }

   static func setCopyNonAtomic<T>(value: T?, to object: Any, forKey key: UnsafeRawPointer) {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(object, key, value, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC)
   }

   static func setRetain<T>(value: T?, to object: Any, forKey key: UnsafeRawPointer) {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(object, key, value, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
   }

   static func setCopy<T>(value: T?, to object: Any, forKey key: UnsafeRawPointer) {
      objc_setAssociatedObject(object, key, value, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY)
   }
}
```

Comment: Works for now. Thank you.

Comment: @Fabian  : COul dyou post if you have any working example .

Comment: @Vlad: Please share if you have inputs

Comment: @EXC_BAD_ACCESS I do not have access to that code anymore, sorry. Good luck!

Comment: What is "com.mc.navigationController" ?