# Porting from iOS to OS X

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

I have to port an iOS application to OS X. I have a little experience with iOS (although I didn't write the applications) and I would like have some suggests.

1) The application has some nice animations -- should I use Quartz to do them on OS X?

2) How can I change the View to have the same effect as the UINAvigationController on OSX? I searched for this component in the Object Library inside Interface Builder but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is liable to be quite an involved process, as (for example) none of the UIKit classes (currently) exist on Mac OS X.

As such, it's likely that you'll only be able to meaningfully retain the model level classes and that a substantial amount of the remaining code may need to be re-written.

Comment: @pedr0 There is no equivalent UINavigationController class on Mac OS X. (As I've said none of the UI* classes exist.) However, the existing [UINavigationController-Alike for Desktop-Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853209/uinavigationcontroller-alike-for-desktop-cocoa) question may help.

Comment: @pedr0: If you make an app on Moc OSX that has a UI just like the same app on iOS, it will be rubbish.  You'll need to redesign the UI from scratch because a computer is a different proposition to write a UI for than a touch controlled device with a comparatively small screen.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be that you thoroughly prepare checklist that contains all tasks. It is not that simple as just looking for equivalent classes in Application Kit to UIKit classes.

it also depends on how app is written. If it has followed MVC properly, then complete files of business logic can be taken without any problems. If not, you will more or less write your new mac app from the scratch.

1. Yes, Core Animation is always a way to go in this cases, but it may happen that you'll encounter a lot of work because of possible different dimensions.
2. UINavigationController is something that doesn't exist on "normal" desktop interfaces. The closest equivalents are tab menus/tab sheets and you know how different they are.

If I were you, I would focus on binging content on the Mac, forget about interface concepts from iOS and rather make new interface concepts on the Mac that are compliant with Apple guidelines.

Comment: +1 especially for the last sentence. I tried a couple of apps from the Mac App Store last weekend. And it's disgusting how many of them exactly duplicate the touch interface of the ipad. Some are completely unusable (at least if you don't like to travel miles with your mouse), and 95% of the apps from publishers that were focused on iOS before the mac app store are frustrating me after minutes of use.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Application Kit and UIKit haven't merged yet, as the iPhones/iPads and iMacs hasn't. At least not yet. Imagine what would programmers have to achieve, if iMac could be used with keyboard or you could slide it in leaned, almost horizontal position and used it like iPad.

Comment: In this case developers would have to switch between "UIKit mode" and "AppKit mode" on-the-fly, handling it like rotation. And I know how much work I can have with implementing rotation in sensible way in some proprietary complex controls I have built... So, Apple is not only about iXxxxx stuff, respect Mac as well :)