# Get UINavigationController-like behavior in a Mac application

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-sheet

I'm very new for mac application. Previously I've worked only for iPhone application and now  I've started to learn mac application. I've created a simple application, for every application we have default toolbar at the top of the screen. So on clicking new I want to stay on the current window and switch to different view where I've a back button on clicking that I want to move back to previous view. Same as in iphone "***PushviewController***" and "***Popviewcontroller***" please suggest me any way. I've tried with following code but they are not working properly as I need.

```
-(IBAction)newDocument:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"<><><>Test");

    NewWindow *newWindow = [[[NewWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"NewWindow"] autorelease];
    NSView *view = [[newWindow window] contentView];
    NSLog(@"%@",view);
    [[self window] setContentView:view];
    //[[newWindow window] becomeKeyWindow];
    //[NSApp beginSheet:[newWindow window] modalForWindow:[self window] modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];

}

- (IBAction)goBack:(NSButton *)sender
{
    [[self window] resignKeyWindow];
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question but I would like to suggest that, if you're interested in learning to write Mac applications, you should make them behave like Mac applications instead of iPhone ones.

Comment: From the opposite direction, if you're writing Mac apps to behave like iOS apps, you'll want to look [Chameleon](http://chameleonproject.org/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22409798/1208191