# Navigation controller in Mac app, similar to iOS app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface

I'm looking to make a Mac app with a navigation controller similar how [Growlvoice](http://www.growlvoice.com/) does theirs. By that, I mean I want my mac app to have a header. When clicking an item in a TableView, it will navigate to the "detailed" view for that item, and the header will update itself with a "back" button, and clicking it will pop you back to the TableView.

My question is — how do you recommend setting up the navigation structure so something like that can be supported in a Mac app? I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853209/uinavigationcontroller-alike-for-desktop-cocoa) recommends [UMeKit](https://github.com/itod/umekit), but I also see that the last commit for that project was 3 years ago. I'm curious if there is a best practice before diving in.

Thanks!

To be clear, this is what I'm looking for.

Table view

[image]

Detail view (with "back" button that says "inbox")

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Chameleon](http://chameleonproject.org), but it seems to be abandoned too.

Your best bet is probably looking at both of these projects and seeing what bits of them you can learn from and incorporate into yours.