# How to Design NavigationController for mac/cocoa App?

Tags: macos, cocoa, navigationcontroller

I want to design navigation flow for mac app (Cocoa Desktop app) same as NavigationController with a Navigation bar and Back button. And also push/pop actions. Same as mac AppStore navigation. Attached screenshots for quick reference.

Is there any mac component available or any third party sources?[image: Screen1]

[image: Screen2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UINavigationController-Alike for Desktop-Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853209/uinavigationcontroller-alike-for-desktop-cocoa)

Comment: @Willeke Nope . That's why posted differenlt.

Comment: Hi, have you got any solution for this?