# MacOS transitions between screens

Tags: swift, macos, storyboard

macOS, storyboard, Swift

I created a new window and made a segue. But it seems that in macOS when I click a button on the first screen, it opens the second screen beside. How can I make it work like iOS that opens the new window on top and hide the first window?

Another example of the behavior that I am looking for is the Mac Preferences windows.

What I have tried
- In storyboard I have put a new View Controller from library
- I put a button in ViewController and make a segue to SecondViewController
- I create a new file > Cocoa Touch Class > Subclass of UIViewController
- In Main.storyboard select Second View Controller> Identity inspector > Class > SecondViewController
- I have put a button in ViewController to go to SecondViewController and I have made a segue in Storyboard.

I am aware that I can select the segue and in Attributes select Sheet. But that makes the new window appear from the top. How can I control that, and make it more like iOS or macOS Preferences examples I mentioned?

Comment: If you are looking for a `UINavigationController`-like behaviour, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853209/uinavigationcontroller-alike-for-desktop-cocoa) will help?